# Wordpress: check if current post is first in the loop

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to style the first post in the loop differently from the rest in a wordpress theme template. Is there a specific wordpress function to check for this or do I just need to set a "first" flag like the below?

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php the_post(); ?>

    <?php if ( $first = !isset( $first ) ) : ?>

        <!-- First Post HTML -->

    <?php else : ?>

        <!-- Every other posts HTML -->

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The function I'm looking for would replace the `$first = ! isset( $first)` check. Does this function exist in WordPress?

Comment: I think the code you post will be the best solution for you, wordpress doesn't have any function tells if post is first.

Comment: @joint thanks - I'll just have to move the logic up a level was hoping to use it in a sub-template where I wouldn't have `$first` in scope.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php $Inc=0; ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php the_post(); ?>

    <?php if ( $Inc==0 ) : ?>

        <!-- First Post HTML -->

    <?php else : ?>

        <!-- Every other posts HTML -->

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $Inc++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: his current version is better than this

Comment: he asked for wordpress function like 'is_first_post()' (which doesn't exist), not how to check this in other way